# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum creates black thumbnail in camera roll

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I am saving image in the camera roll using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum but always get an black thumbnail even if the picture is correct.

Do you have pointers to address this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Drawing the image within a UIGraphicsImageContext solves the issue:

```
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
  UIImage *image = ((put here your image));

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
  [image drawInRect:rect];
  UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(
      result, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
```